# Mac OS X Network User account login with local admin password

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

At a previous job, we had our Mac server configured so that we could log into client machines using any network user account name and the local admin password.  I can't seem to find out how this was accomplished, and google isn't turning up anything particularly useful.  Does anyone know exactly how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you probably had the "Enable administrator to masquerade as any registered user" option set. More info available by Googling this phrase. See point 6 of [this document](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=ServerAdmin/10.4/en/c3fs3.html) for initial Tiger specific info. I think Leopard is the same, but I have no Leopard Server close by at the moment, so I can't check.

In my Leopard-based Server Admin tool controlling my Tiger server, the option is under the AFP Service section, Settings subsection, Access tab.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is correct, I just wasnt remembering the correct way to get into the user's account.
While logged in as an admin, in Finder,  Go> Connect to Server... enter the server address and when it asks you to log in, put in the user's username and the admin password.
I thought I had remembered actually logging in through the login window with the user's username and admin password, but I may have been mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect this means that your Mac's were authenticating against some sort of directory service, in your case most likely [OSX Open Directory](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/technology/open-directory.html), other options include active directory, open LDAP or other services. This is a centralised directory of user accounts that can be used on any machine in that or organisation.

There is a good article [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/57477/2007/04/opendirectory.html) discussing the concepts of Open Directory. For actual setup instructions, [this](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9019898/Hands_on_Setting_up_Mac_OS_X_Open_Directory) is a good guide.